# LibCurl seems to escape my POSTFIELDS

Tags: c++, post, curl

I'm using this code to post json to a server:

But it seems like CURL somewhere in the way escapes the data, i.e transforms it into
*"{\"email\":\"test@example.se\"}"* (Makes my quotes escaped).
I think curl still posts with the Content-Type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", even thou I've overwritten it with application/json in my headers.
How can I make curl not do that?

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
const std::string& data = "{\"email\":\"test@example.se\"}";
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data.c_str() );
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, data.size() );
// Headers
curl_easy_setopt(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
curl_easy_setopt(headers, "Authorization: Basic: something:something");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Comment: libcurl simply has no code that escapes or converts that data!

Comment: @DanielStenberg Thinking about it I think it might be that the server expects utf8 and not ansi. I will try it first tomorrow at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html

libcurl will not convert or encode it for you in any way.

The data pointed to is NOT copied by the library: as a consequence, it must be preserved by the calling application until the associated transfer finishes.

Are you sure you are following these notices?

Comment: Yes, all those notices are followed.

Comment: Can you check the string immediately after creation, to see if it contains the backslashes. Perhaps the compiler is doing it?

Comment: Checked it, it doesnt contain any backslashes. I think the problem is the encoding CURL does somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps it is something on the receiving end adding them in?